# How do I create a Python 3.3 environment with Anaconda (& Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, python, path, environment-variables

I installed Anaconda on my Windows XP machine about a week ago.  It came with Python 2.7.

I am trying to create a Python 3.3 environment on it.  I followed [these directions](http://docs.continuum.io/conda/intro.html), resulting in downloading a bunch of stuff, with no error messages.

The instructions said I had to change my path, but they did not say how.  There are new folders called `I:\Python33` and `I:\Anaconda\envs\py33` on my PC.  I added `I:\Python33` to my `PATH`.

I shut down and restarted Anaconda several times.  I cannot get `import scitools.pprint2` to work in a Python interpreter (I think I need Python 3.3 for this).

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-8852894fb85d>", line 1, in <module>
    import scitools.pprint2

ImportError: No module named scitools.pprint2
```

How should I troubleshoot this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try:

```
$ conda create -p path\to\your\virtualenv python=3.3 nameOfVirtualenv
```

Comment: Would that be in place of a certain line or would it be on its own?

Comment: The is a command to be run from terminal (cmd). Or did I get You wrong?

Comment: No, it's not my question, I was just asking for some clarification on the answer

Comment: I expect it to be a clean new anaconda virtualenv with python3.3.

Comment: @StefanSmith: I thought there should be the name of the virtualenv at the end. Looks like it doesn't. Can You remove that and try again?

Comment: @Adobe : Thanks again.  I entered " conda create -p path\to\your\virtualenv python=3.3 " at the command line.  Then I got a response that python-3.3.2 would be linked, then "Linking packages...", then "COMPLETE".  No error messages.  Then I launched Anaconda.  I entered " import scitools.pprint2 " at an IPython console.  I got the same error message that I reported in my original question.

Comment: @Adobe : The reason I am trying to get Python 3.3 to work is that I thought I needed it to get "import scitools.pprint2" to work.  Is that premise correct?  If not, can you suggest a possible way to get "import scitools.pprint2" to work?

Comment: You have to import `scitools` first: `import scitools`. After that You'll be able to `import scitools.pprint2`. And I don't think python3.3 was a prerequisite for this.

Comment: @Adobe : I ended up uninstalling Anaconda, installing Python 3.3 from the main Python site, and installing Scitools separately.

Comment: I think You should only move to anaconda a) once You master vanilla python ecosystem b) once You really *have to*. Otherwise it's just another setup level.

Answer (score 5):

This has been cleaned up a bit.  You can now do:

```
conda update conda  
conda create -n py33 python=3.3 anaconda
activate py33
```

Unfortunately scitools fails to build still, are you sure it's python 3 compatible?

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't really done anything with Python in a long time.  Matlab, Octave, and Maple seem to do everything I need.  A previous commenter recommended against using anaconda until I'd mastered basic python.  I'm a math person, not a computer person, and unfortunately it seem difficult for a non-computer type to install and use a really good GUI for Python, let alone decide which one to use.  Eventually, if I move to a "real" language, I would like to use Python.

Comment: I think those are all great systems.  If you do plan on using Python, I actually disagree with your commenter.  Anaconda will use all the tools needed to get started (just like Matlab and others).  It includes the excellent Spyder GUI.  Good luck!

Comment: I have done this successfully. One tips, download miniconda instead of Anaconda. Since we are going to setup all 3.3 Anaconda packages, there is no point in installing the 2.7 anaconda, which takes 1.5 GB disc space. miniconda includes only the base Python and you can install your choice of packages later.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the anaconda Navigator. It is installed by default with recent enough Anaconda installer.

In the `Environments` tab, you click on `Create` button and you set the name and the Python version you want to use:

[image]

From this menu, you can also launch the terminal, a Python command line, an IPython command line and the Jupyther notebook, all with the environment you choose:
[image]

I think it's what you where missing: stating Python with the new environment.

You can do the same with command line, but for the usage you described this graphical way may suit you better.